# Using a name selector instead of an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the following code to work off of a `name` selector instead of the `id`?

```
<div id="light" class="change_group_popup">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.change_group').on('click',function(){
    $("#light,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    });

    $('.close').on('click',function(){
        $("#light,.white_overlay").fadeOut("slow");
     });
```

UPDATE:

I added more of my code to show the loop to help explain what I am doing in more detail.

```
$runUsers2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
$numrows2 = mysqli_num_rows($run2);

    if( $numrows2 ) {
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
            if($row2['status'] == "Approved"){
            //var_dump ($row2);

                $approved_id        = $row2['user_id'];
                $approved_firstname = $row2['firstname'];
                $approved_lastname  = $row2['lastname'];
                $approved_username  = $row2['username'];
                $approved_email  = $row2['email'];

    if ($approved_firstname == true) {
        echo "Name - ". $approved_firstname . " " . $approved_lastname . "</br>" . 
            "Username - ". $approved_username . "</br></br>"
?>
<div class="change_group_button"> 
     <a class="change_group" href="javascript:void(0)">Change User Permission</a>
</div><br>
<div class="change_group_popup light">
    <a class="close" href="javascript:void(0)">Close</a>
 <div class="group_success" style="color: red;"></div><br>
    <form class="update_group" action="" method="POST">
       <div class="field">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_id; ?>" name="approved_id" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_firstname; ?>" name="approved_firstname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_lastname; ?>" name="approved_lastname" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_username; ?>" name="approved_username" />
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $approved_email; ?>" name="approved_email" />
        <select name='group_id' required>
```

Comment: Sample html actually showing "name" could help with precise answer....

Comment: But the `name` attribute should only be used on input elements. Why do you need it in this code?

Comment: I am using it in a loop and it is messing up my other javascript in my php loop.

Comment: I would normally make it a class, but it already had one.

Comment: Strange policy... Normally it is fine to have multiple classes. Why can't you?

Comment: So I can do this? `$('.change_group').on('click',function(){
    $(".light,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");
    });`... with this `<div class="change_group_popup light">`

Comment: @Paul: An element can have multiple classes. Put the classes space separated in the `class` attribute: `class="change_group_popup light"`

Comment: Paul, yes. side note: based on your "loop" comment you may actually want to use parent or some other relative selectors if you have multiple clckable elements on the page.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov what exactly do you mean by this? Any examples?

Comment: @Barmar `name` can also be used on `<form>` and `<a>` though both are obsolete / deprecated with HTML5

Comment: @Phil  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes doesn't list `<a>`. But since he wants to use it on `<div>`, that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Paul Something like `$(this).find(".light, .white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I was able to get my pop up to come up with `$(".light,.white_overlay").fadeIn("slow");`, but for some reason when I use yours it will not come up. I think I need something like what you posted to get the correct pop up, but not sure why it won't display.

Comment: It would help if you showed more of the HTML. Your HTML doesn't include  the `change_group` element, so I was just making an assumption that it contains the `light` and `white_overlay` elements. That's why I said it was something like that -- you need to adjust it to match your actual design.

Comment: @Barmar I added more of the HTML.

Comment: Is there more than one `change_group_button`? How are they related to the `light` and `white_overlay` elements that should fade out?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, there are more than one. There is one for every user in my site. I added more code to show the loop. I was told that no matter which change group button I click on that it would show the same info because of this pop up.

Comment: Where is `white_overlay` in your HTML?

Comment: @Barmar `white_overlay` is my css class for the pop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM traversal functions to find the related element.

```
$(".change_group").click(function() {
    var light = $(this).closest(".change_group_button").nextAll(".light").first(); // Find the next .light DIV after the button
    light.add($(".white_overlay")).fadeIn("slow");
}):
```

Comment: Any errors? Maybe you can make a jsfiddle with the HTML?

Comment: I fixed it to put the click handler on `.change_group`, and then go up a level to `.change_group_button` before getting the next `.light`.

Comment: Awsome! I saw the version you had before this and tried it, I had to put a `);` at the end and then it worked, but I tried this newest version and it worked just as well. Are there really any differences between them in?

Comment: The difference is whether you want the click handler on the whole DIV or just the A. Since there's nothing else in the DIV, there's not much difference.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a huger headache!

Answer (score 2):

You can get any element by name attribute by:

```
$('[name="someName"]')
```